# Calculate rate by group with sapply

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, sapply

I have a data like this:
This is just a fake data I create:

```
# dt
Col1      Col2   Col3   Col4
2014/1/1  A        10   1
2014/4/1  A        15   1.5
2015/1/1  A        15   3
2015/4/1  A        30   4
2014/1/1  B        20   2
2014/4/1  B        30   6
2015/1/1  B        40   10
2015/4/1  B        80   16
```

What I want:

```
Col1      Col2   Col3   Col4   Col3.R   Col4.R
2014/1/1  A        10   1      1        1
2014/4/1  A        15   1.5    1.5      1.5
2015/1/1  A        15   3      1.5      3
2015/4/1  A        30   4      3        4
2014/1/1  B        20   2      1        1
2014/4/1  B        30   6      3/2      3
2015/1/1  B        40   10     2        5
2015/4/1  B        80   16     4        8
```

The new column `Col3.R` is calculated by the value of `col3` under each group `Col2` divide the first value in each group. Same as `col4.R`.

I try the code below:

```
dt[, sapply(.SD, function(x) R = x / x[1]), .SDcols = 3:4, by = .(Col2)]
```

How to keep the original columns? Do I need to use argument `on` for `data.table`?

Data:

```
dt <- fread("    Col1      Col2   Col3   Col4
2014/1/1  A        10   1
2014/4/1  A        15   1.5
2015/1/1  A        15   3
2015/4/1  A        30   4
2014/1/1  B        20   2
2014/4/1  B        30   6
2015/1/1  B        40   10
2015/4/1  B        80   16", header = T)
dt$Col3 <- as.numeric(dt$Col3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lapply` and `paste0` to create new columns

```
library(data.table)

dt[, paste0("col", 3:4, ".R") := lapply(.SD, 
           function(x) x / x[1]), .SDcols = 3:4, by = .(Col2)]

dt
#       Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 col3.R col4.R
#1: 2014/1/1    A   10  1.0    1.0    1.0
#2: 2014/4/1    A   15  1.5    1.5    1.5
#3: 2015/1/1    A   15  3.0    1.5    3.0
#4: 2015/4/1    A   30  4.0    3.0    4.0
#5: 2014/1/1    B   20  2.0    1.0    1.0
#6: 2014/4/1    B   30  6.0    1.5    3.0
#7: 2015/1/1    B   40 10.0    2.0    5.0
#8: 2015/4/1    B   80 16.0    4.0    8.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `.SD` in `paste0()`?

Comment: @PeterChen you already know the position of the columns , right? You are using it in `SDcols`.

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'Col2', specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table and divide by the `first` element of x

```
dt[, paste0(names(dt)[3:4],  ".R") := 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) x/first(x)), .SDcols = 3:4, by = .(Col2)] 
dt
#       Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col3.R Col4.R
#1: 2014/1/1    A   10  1.0    1.0    1.0
#2: 2014/4/1    A   15  1.5    1.5    1.5
#3: 2015/1/1    A   15  3.0    1.5    3.0
#4: 2015/4/1    A   30  4.0    3.0    4.0
#5: 2014/1/1    B   20  2.0    1.0    1.0
#6: 2014/4/1    B   30  6.0    1.5    3.0
#7: 2015/1/1    B   40 10.0    2.0    5.0
#8: 2015/4/1    B   80 16.0    4.0    8.0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>%
    group_by(Col2) %>%
    mutate_at(3:4, list(R = ~ ./first(.)))
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   Col2 [2]
#  Col1     Col2   Col3  Col4 Col3_R Col4_R
#  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2014/1/1 A        10   1      1      1  
#2 2014/4/1 A        15   1.5    1.5    1.5
#3 2015/1/1 A        15   3      1.5    3  
#4 2015/4/1 A        30   4      3      4  
#5 2014/1/1 B        20   2      1      1  
#6 2014/4/1 B        30   6      1.5    3  
#7 2015/1/1 B        40  10      2      5  
#8 2015/4/1 B        80  16      4      8
```

Comment: If my original column names are complicated. Not `col3` & `col4`, `paste0()` is a little bit difficult to create the new column

Comment: @PeterChen  If you know the column position, the names can be extracted i.e. `names(dt)[3:4]